# Numeric value inside varchar MySQL in temporary table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

## Problem

I have a field with values like

```
 "ABC1234"
 "ABC5678/DEF"
 "AB1298"
 "AB1298/DEF"
```

I want to extract the numeric value from each one of it, such as:

```
  1234
  5678
  1298
  1298
```

*NOTE: The numeric value is always "together" (1234) and is always composed by 4 digits only.*

> I was trying to delete first the double quotes to use RegEx: SELECT REPLACE(model_name,'''','') FROM ProductList **Note: I replace using ' single quote instead of double quotes " , because that's the way the data was saved, and it works.** And then I tried to use Patindex to get the numeric value: SELECT SUBSTRING(field, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', field), LEN(field)) **NOTE: However, PATINDEX does not work with MySQL**

I'm trying to do this, because then I want to separate each value in two different columns by creating a temporary table:

> SELECT SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')-1) AS col_one, SUBSTR(t.column_one, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')+1) AS col_two FROM YOUR_TABLE t

```
   val1    val2
    12       34
    56       78
    12       98
```

*Note: I'm using PHPMyAdmin within XAMPP.*

> After PATINDEX, I tried LOCATION, and POSITION. (You can see the sequence of the test print screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfQjo.jpg) ) SELECT SUBSTRING(model_name,LOCATE('%[^0-9]%',model_name),4) FROM ProductList **NOTE: The LOCATE or POSITION function is returning a position 0, and that's why there is no result. I can imagine the problem is in "%[^0-9]%", because not LOCATE, POSITION nor MID accept RegEx.**

**My next problem is**: I want to have the *lval* and *rval* inside the temporary table *footprint*, created at the beginning of the query. This, because I would like to create queries by getting input texts values, and have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM footprint WHERE lval=50;

      model_name     num_pos    lval     rval
      ''ABC1234''        7       12       34
    ''ABC1234/DEF''      7       50       78
    ''ABDCE1234''        8       12       98
```

## Solution Proposal

At the end, I want to search the name_model, depending on the values of lval and rval. So the next "query" works for me:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS footprint AS
(SELECT model_name, 
  LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',model_name) >0,Locate('0',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('1',model_name) >0,Locate('1',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('2',model_name) >0,Locate('2',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('3',model_name) >0,Locate('3',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('4',model_name) >0,Locate('4',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('5',model_name) >0,Locate('5',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('6',model_name) >0,Locate('6',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('7',model_name) >0,Locate('7',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('8',model_name) >0,Locate('8',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('9',model_name) >0,Locate('9',model_name),999)
  ) AS num_Pos
FROM ProductList) ;
SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, left(val,2) AS lval, right(val,2) AS rval FROM
(SELECT MID(pl.model_name, fp.num_Pos,4) AS val, pl.model_name AS name FROM ProductList AS pl INNER JOIN footprint AS fp ON fp.model_name=pl.model_name) p) n WHERE lval='50' and rval='50'
```

*If you have any other suggestion about how this process could be done or improved, please let me know.*

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: Is the numeric part always 4 characters?

Comment: @GB Yes, my problem is they have different positions in the "string" (as it is shown in the first examples). Thanks.

Comment: You can use the code on your "solution" query with little tweaks. Something like `SELECT MID(col, LEAST(...), 2) AS a, MID(col, LEAST(...) + 2, 2) as b FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all the description I wrote, the next code ended working for me.
A lot of hints are hiding in the description, but if you have any suggestion about the query, be my guest.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS footprint AS
(SELECT model_name, 
  LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',model_name) >0,Locate('0',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('1',model_name) >0,Locate('1',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('2',model_name) >0,Locate('2',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('3',model_name) >0,Locate('3',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('4',model_name) >0,Locate('4',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('5',model_name) >0,Locate('5',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('6',model_name) >0,Locate('6',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('7',model_name) >0,Locate('7',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('8',model_name) >0,Locate('8',model_name),999),
    if (Locate('9',model_name) >0,Locate('9',model_name),999)
  ) AS num_Pos
FROM ProductList) ;
SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, left(val,2) AS lval, right(val,2) AS rval FROM
(SELECT MID(pl.model_name, fp.num_Pos,4) AS val, pl.model_name AS name FROM ProductList AS pl INNER JOIN footprint AS fp ON fp.model_name=pl.model_name) p) n WHERE lval='50' and rval='50'
```

Answer (score 0):

a double quote is a distinct character not simply 2 single quotes so to strip off the double quotes try.

```
SELECT REPLACE(model_name,'"','') FROM ProductList
```

you are sooo close with the code above. given that your numeric portion will always be 4 chars you could use something like this

```
declare @t as table(field varchar(15))

insert into @t 
values
    ('"ABC1234"'),
    ('"ABC5678/DEF"'),
    ('"AB1298"'),
    ('"AB1298/DEF"')

select left(val,2) as lval, right(val,2) as rval
from
    (select  SUBSTRING(field, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', field), 4) val
    from @t) t
```

so with the context of your database it would be something like

```
select left(val,2) as lval, right(val,2) as rval
    from
        (select  SUBSTRING(model_name, POSITION('%[0-9]%', model_name), 4) val
        from ProductList) p
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, it works with '' and not with ", somehow the data was saved like that.

Comment: cool, I have added to my answer above for the main part of your question.

Comment: I think something go lost there but reading between the lines - yes just replace @t with ProductList, and field with model_name, and you can call the derived columns whatever you wish.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong because I get the next error [Link](https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/OV5bqNYBlld/O~cSF3EgAwXSXN_1)   Thanks.

Comment: can you just paste the error in there for me... for some reason I cant get to that image.

Comment: Sure, 

The last error was: #1064 An error in the syntax 

((( https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/OV5bqNYBlld/O~cSF3EgAwXSXN_1 )))

Then I tried it again, and this was shown:
Error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias 
(((( https://www.uploady.com/download/MXuZmrVMgRJ/SGEpsYjmLfXNMZ81 )))))

Comment: In my answer above the `t` after the derived table is the alias, I chose t but it can be anything you want, but there must be one.

Comment: Error #1305 Function dbo.PATINDEX does not exist [link](http://imgur.com/a/73G3d)

Comment: If you are using MySQL then use POSITION function - this is why we always ask for which DB engine you are using it helps us provide relevant answers... I assumed SQL Server because you used PATINDEX in your question.

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry, I didn't know about the POSITION function, I will search for it. Thanks.

Comment: Its all good, no worries. It has the same syntax so should work after you change the function name.

Comment: So, at the beginning I was getting an error with the whole query together, and I decided to try it separately. So far, the POSITION or LOCATION functions are not returning a valid value:

[Queries Album](http://imgur.com/a/73G3d)

Answer (score 0):

To split the numeric and the string part of your values you can use `trim`, like this:

```
SELECT trim(field, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"') AS col0, trim(field, '1234567890"') AS col1 FROM table
```

Hope it help.

**P.S.**

This solution also work on sqlite database where the function `PATINDEX` doesn't exisit.

Comment: Somehow it didn't work for me, I tried this:

       -->    SELECT rtrim(ltrim(model_name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"'), '"') AS col0, ltrim(rtrim(model_name, '1234567890"'), '"') AS col1 FROM ProductList

///// But I got an error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ltrim'

I'm using phpmyadmin as you can see in the image
[PrintScr](https://www.uploady.com/download/ASiMj1~tqWF/nSQPo2drHz4H07rk)

Thanks.

Comment: My bad. My solution doesn't seem to work **only** with SQLite. I edited my solution for an even better one, using one trim instead of ltrim/rtrim. But still only for SQLite. Sorry.